# Subir multiples imagenes symfony 3

Tags: symfony2, symfony3, doctrine2

Tengo un problema:Tengo una entidad Propiedad y entre sus campos uno denominado fotoUbicacion.La cuestion es la siguiente,necesito que ese campo almacene la cantidad de imagenes que suba el usuario en el formulario. En la documentacion de symfony 3.4(https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/controller/upload_file.html).Pero solo muestran como subir un archivo...que modificaciones tendría que realizar para lograr obtener lo que deseo.Acá les dejo mi codigo(de esa manera logro insertar una imagen):
Entity Propiedad:

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="fotoUbicacion", type="string",nullable=true)
 */
private $fotoUbicacion;

    /**
 * Set fotoUbicacion
 *
 * @param string $fotoUbicacion
 *
 * @return Propiedad
 */
public function setFotoUbicacion($fotoUbicacion)
{
    $this->fotoUbicacion= $fotoUbicacion;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get fotoUbicacion
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getFotoUbicacion()
{
    return $this->fotoUbicacion;
}
//Config.yml
    parameters:
locale: en
imagenes_directorio: '%kernel.project_dir%/web/uploads/imagenes_propiedades'
fotos_ubicacion_directorio: '%kernel.project_dir%/web/uploads/fotos_ubicacion'
//Controller
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $propiedad = new Propiedad();
    $form = $this->createForm('Assertsoft\InmobiliariaBundle\Form\PropiedadType', $propiedad);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {


        $file2 = $propiedad->getFotoUbicacion();
        $fileName2 = $this->generateUniqueFileName().'.'.$file2->guessExtension();
        $file2->move($this->getParameter('fotos_ubicacion_directorio'),$fileName2);
        $propiedad->setFotoUbicacion($fileName2);

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($propiedad);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('propiedad_show', array('id' => $propiedad->getId()));
    }

    return $this->render('@AssertsoftInmobiliaria/propiedad/new.html.twig', array(
        'propiedad' => $propiedad,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}

    private function generateUniqueFileName()
{
    // md5() reduces the similarity of the file names generated by
    // uniqid(), which is based on timestamps
    return md5(uniqid());
}

//formtype
->add('fotoUbicacion',FileType::class,array('attr'=>array('onchange'=>'onChange(event)','multiple' => true)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$image = new Image();
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($image)
        ->add('full', FileType::class, array('label' => 'Imagen', 'multiple' => true))
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Guardar'))
        ->getForm();
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $files = $image->getFull();
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $image = new Image();
            $fileName = $fileUploader->upload($file);
            $image->setFull('uploads/images/' . $fileName);
            }
    }
```

A mi me funciona perfecto de esta manera.
Full es la dirección de la imagen.